# Creating a smart linked list

Tags: c, struct

I am trying to create a linked list where I am checking if the second or the others after the second one already exists in the previous elements

for example i want to add a b c a

it should notify that a is already in the linked list

Not sure how to go about this logic

so far this is what i am thinking about

... create struct

```
typedef struct check
{
   char *names;
   struct check *next;
} HERE;

some_func(*char name)
{

  HERE *all = malloc(sizeof(HERE));
  all->names = 
  all->next = NULL;


 while(all != NULL)
 {
   // if strcmp ...

 }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this would be to sort the list (a tag-array insertion sort is sensible if you're working from real-time user input), and after finding the resting place of a new entry, check if the entry before or after (depending on your sort code, you should only need to check one or the other) is the same.  This requires only a couple more data reads than the insertion sort's search, and no additional moves (even of tag values), so should add little to sort time and avoid excessive complication of the code.